# How can I get the selected value of a combobox (and store it in a variable)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been wondering how can I get the current value of a combobox (not the current()) and preferably store it to my variable 'listvalue'. I've been searching for a while but never found anything that I wanted.
Here's the sample code:

```
FontList1['values'] = ("Courier","Courier New","Times New Roman","Comic Sans MS")
FontList1.set(TypeFace)
print(listvalue)
FontList1.pack(side="right")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the selected font in a tkinter StringVar?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

selectedFontVar = tk.StringVar()

FontList1 = ttk.Combobox(root,textvariable=selectedFontVar,postcommand=displayFont)
FontList1['values'] = ("Courier","Courier New","Times New Roman","Comic Sans MS")
FontList1.pack()

SelectedFont = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=selectedFontVar)
SelectedFont.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you want to get the selected font, you can just call `selectedFontVar.get()' which will return whatever is selected in the combobox.

Advantage of a StringVar is that is is automatically updated when the combobox changes and this change can 'cascade' down to other widgets that also use the same stringvar. Like SelectedFont in my example.